# GNU Screen behavior when the program running on it terminates

Tags: gnu-screen

I was going through the GNU Screen manual and [it says](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Overview)

> When a program terminates, screen (per default) kills the window that
>   contained it. If this window was in the foreground, the display
>   switches to the previously displayed window; if none are left, screen
>   exits

However in practice doesn't seem so. Neither for the screen nor for the windows. For example if I start a screen and run the program `who` or any other program, the program runs and terminates but the screen or window is still there. What am I reading wrong?

Comment: That you didn't start `screen` with `who`, but your shell, and that shell continues to live on.

Comment: whoever downvoted plz explain why so that I am more careful in future. Nowhere in the reference it was mentioned that it's about "the program" it starts with so it wouldn't be clear to a learner and I couldn't find a related question on SE either. So it's seems like a legitimate question to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start `screen`, then type `who` at the prompt, then it is the shell that *runs in `screen`* that executes `who`.  `screen` will therefore not terminate until that shell terminates.

To make `screen` run `who` instead of your shell, invoke `screen` like

```
screen who
```

The same behavior may be observed with `tmux`:

```
tmux new-session who
```

... where `new-session` (or just `new` for short) is a `tmux` command that initiates a new `tmux` session, and which takes a shell command to run in that session as an argument.

Comment: thank you. clearer now. trying to get some grip on screen and their windows.